# SwiftUI using instance variable in @FetchRequest

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, swiftui

I am trying to use a instance variable in my FetchRequest. I do understand that I can not use the instance variable as my `init` hasn't been called yet.

I tried doing my FetchRequest in the init instead, which works, however isn't updated when the data changes. Is there a chance to use `@FetchRequest` which updates automatically, and using my instance variable?

I can not declare `@FetchRequest` inside the init. Any other solution?

That is my `@FetchRequest`

```
@FetchRequest(entity: PersonVenueMapping.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key:"", ascending: true)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "person == %@", PersonFormVenues.personStatic!)) var test123: FetchedResults<PersonVenueMapping>
```

I am using `person` as instance variable. That's why I am getting the error.

That is my code in the init:

```
//Declaration
var personVenueMapping = [PersonVenueMapping]()

let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "", ascending: true)

var test : NSFetchRequest<PersonVenueMapping> = PersonVenueMapping.fetchRequest()
test.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "person == %@", person)

do {
    self.personVenueMapping = try NSManagedObjectContext.current.fetch(test)
} catch
{
}
```

I thought of using `@State` for my `personVenueMapping`, however setting the initial data didn't work correctly either.

**TL:DR:** I want the functionality of @FetchRequest, and still use my instance variable.

Comment: This might help: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/dynamically-filtering-fetchrequest-with-swiftui

Comment: @Mamaessen Thank you so much :) I was able to solve my problem with that tutorial. Vielen Dank :)